# Binding select tag data to reactive form in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I've a JSON formatted data coming from back-end, with gender as a select tag in front-end I'm unable to pre-select the option that comes with json data. Also from back-end it comes in `enum` format and I need it to parse accordingly `1` for `Male` and `2` for `Female`
here is the format of my back-end data,

```
{
  "salesPersonId": 13,
  "name": "testName",
  "gender": 1,
  "phone1": "34986215",
  "phone2": "string",
  "email": "testingEmail@example.com",
  "team": "Bravo",
  "teamLeader": "Delta",
  "countyId": 1,
  "county": null,
  "subCountyId": 1,
  "subCounty": null,
  "address": "House 108",
  "additionalInfo": "He Drinks tea",
  "input1": "string",
  "input2": "string"
}
```

and here's what I'm trying to get it bind with my received data,

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="33" class="pr-4">
    <mat-label>Gender</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="gender">
        <mat-option value="1">1</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="2">2</mat-option>

    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

neither it produces any error nor do it pre-select the gender tag that comes from back-end.
Note: I'm using reactive forms
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your form configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setValue` method in Angular Forms as follows.

I will assume that you are using `FormGroup`. In HTML `value` should be used as a property binding as follows.

```
<form [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Gender</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="gender">
    <mat-option [value]="1">Male</mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="2">Female</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Change your TS as follows.

```
  user = { "name": "testName", "gender": 1 };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myGroup.controls['gender'].setValue(this.user.gender);
  }
```

**[StackBlitz Demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lzh1z6?file=src/app/select-overview-example.html)**